# Python string manipulation moving a character from one spot to another

Tags: python, string

I'm not too sure why this is not working but it's supposed to move the C to the right if . is to the right of it. this does not seem to change the city string at all.

```
import time
city = 'C................R..................'


position = (city.index('C'))

for i in city:
    time.sleep(1)
    if city[position+1] == '.':

        city[position].replace('C','.')
        city[position+1].replace('.','C')

    position = (city.index('C'))

    print(city)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: strings are immutable in python.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like @Ruzihm and @Mark Meyer have mentioned, a string's character can not be replaced as if it is a list. You must convert it to a list first.

But going by the problem you are trying to solve, I am wondering why can't you simply write like this if all you are looking for is making any existence of 'C.' into '.C'. Or am I misunderstanding something?

```
city = 'C................R................C..C'

city = city.replace('C.', '.C')
print(city)
# should output: .C...............R.................C.C
```

Comment: nice use of `replace`

Answer (score 0):

`string.replace` doesn't alter the string in-place. Between that and the fact that strings are immutable in python, I recommend using `city` as a list and just index and assign to the characters/strings you want to change.

You can use `''.join(city)` to convert the list to a string for printing purposes.

Altogether:

```
import time
city = 'C................R..................'
city = list(city)


position = city.index('C')

for i in city:
    time.sleep(1)

    if city[position+1] == '.':
        city[position] = '.'
        city[position+1] = 'C'

    position = city.index('C')
    print(''.join(city))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join CR then this edit will be helpful

```
import time
city = 'C................R..................'

position_C = 0

for i in city:
    time.sleep(1)
    l_city = list(city)
    if l_city[position_C+1] == '.':
        l_city[position_C]="."
        l_city[position_C+1]='C'

        city=''.join(l_city)

    position_C = (city.index('C'))

    print(city)
```

If you want to go beyond R than tell me I will help you out.
Mark answer as accepted if you got what you wanted.